# Errores al unir 3 objetos en un mismo Main

Tags: java, poo, object, objeto

Tengo un ejercicio enfocado a POO en el que me piden 3 objetos diferentes:

1. Fecha

   ```
   public class Fecha {
   //variables
   private int dia;
   private int mes;
   private int anyo;

   //constructor
   public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anyo) {
     this.dia = dia;
     this.mes = mes;
     this.anyo = anyo;
   }

   //metodo
   public String toString(){
     return this.dia + "-" + this.mes + "-" + this.anyo; //creamos la frase devolviendo un string
   }

   //setters y getters
   public boolean setBisiesto(){ //creamos un metodo para comprobar si es bisiesto
    return  ((anyo % 4 == 0) && (anyo % 100 != 0) || (anyo % 400 == 0));
   }

   public int getTotalMes() { //creamos un metodo para establecer la duracion total del mes
   if (mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12){
       return 31;
   } else if(mes == 2){
       if(setBisiesto()){
           return 29;
       }
       else{
           return 28;
       }
   }
   return 30;
   }

   public boolean getFechaCorrecta() { //comprobar si la fecha es correcta
   if(anyo >= 0){
       return false;
   }
   if (mes < 1 || mes > 12){
       return false;
   }
   if (dia > 1 && dia < getTotalMes()){
       return true;
   }
   return false;

   }

   public void setDiaSiguiente() { //metodo para sumar 1 dia a la fecha
   if (dia < getTotalMes()){
       dia++;
       System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);
   } else {
       dia = 1;
       if (mes == 12) {
           anyo++;
           mes = 1;
           System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);
       } else {
           mes++;
           System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);
       }

    }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Persona

   ```
   public class Persona {
    //variables
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String fechaNacimiento;
    private String dni;
    private String direccion;
    private String email;

    //constructor
    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos, String fechaNacimiento, String dni, String direccion,
       String email) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.apellidos = apellidos;
   this.fechaNacimiento = getFechaNacimiento(); //asignamos fecha de nacimiento al metodo anteriormente creado para dar formato.
   this.dni = dni;
   this.direccion = direccion;
   this.email = email;
   }

   //setter
   public String getFechaNacimiento() {
   this.fechaNacimiento = toString(); //le pasamos el formato toString anteriomente creado para la fecha
   return fechaNacimiento;
   }

   public String setPersona() {
   return "Nombre:"+this.nombre+"\nApellidos:"+this.apellidos+"\nFecha de nacimiento:" + this.fechaNacimiento
           +"\nDNI:"+ this.dni+"\nDireccion:"+this.direccion+"\nEmail:"+this.email;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Cuenta

   ```
   public class Cuenta {
   //variables
   private int numCuenta;
   private int interes;
   private int saldo;
   private String cliente;
   private int total;
   private int ingreso;
   private int reintegro;
   private int transferencia;


   //constructor
   public Cuenta(int numCuenta, int interes, int saldo, String cliente, int total, int ingreso, int reintegro,
       int transferencia) {
   this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
   this.interes = interes;
   this.saldo = saldo;
   this.cliente = setPersona();
   this.total = total;
   this.ingreso = ingreso;
   this.reintegro = reintegro;
   this.transferencia = transferencia;
   }

   //metodos setters y getters

   public int getNumCuenta() {
   return numCuenta;
   }

   public void setNumCuenta(int numCuenta) {
   this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
   }

   public int getInteres() {
   return interes;
   }

   public void setInteres(int interes) {
   this.interes = interes;
   }

   public int getSaldo() {
   return saldo;
   }

   public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
   this.saldo = saldo;
   }

   public String getCliente() {
   return cliente;
   }

   public void setCliente(String cliente) {
   this.cliente = cliente;
   }

   public int getTotal() {
   return total;
   }

   public void setTotal(int total) {
   this.total = total;
   }

   public boolean setIngreso(int ingreso) {
   boolean ingresoOk = true; //inicializamos ingreso en true
   if (interes < 0) { //si interes es menor que 0 ingreso es false
       ingresoOk = false; 
   } else { 
       total = total + interes; //sino sumamos el interes con el total de la cuenta
   }
   return ingresoOk;
   }

   public int getIngreso() {
   return ingreso;
   }

   public boolean setReintegro(int reintegro) {
   boolean reintegroOk = true;  //inicializamos reintegro en true
   if (interes < 0) {
       reintegroOk = false; //si reintegro es menor que 0 reintegro es false
   } else if (total >= interes) { //sino si total de la cuenta es mayor o igual al interes
       total -= interes; // total menos interes
   } else {
       reintegroOk = false;
   }
   return reintegroOk;

   }

   public int getReintegro() {
   return reintegro;
   }

   public boolean setTransferencia(int transferencia) {
   boolean transferenciaOk = true; //inicializamos la transferencia en true
   if (interes < 0) {
       transferenciaOk= false; // si es interes en menor a 0 es false
   } else if (total >= interes) { //sino si el total es mayor o igual al interes
      setReintegro(interes); //llamamos a los metodos anteriores
      setIngreso(interes);
   } else {
       transferenciaOk = false; 
   }
   return transferenciaOk;
   }

   public int getTransferencia() {
   return transferencia;
   }

   String setPersona() {
   this.cliente = setPersona(); //indicamos que cliente viene de la clase persona
   return cliente;
   }
   }
   ```

Después de crear cada uno de estos objetos debo crear una clase Main para que se vean los 3 objetos y que se vea que funcionen.
Pero no logro hacer que se vean correctamente por pantalla me da error de ***"main" java.lang.StackOverflowError*** proveniente del objeto cuenta cuando voy a imprimir el resultado, además tampoco me sale bien el resultado de colocar la fecha dentro del objeto persona.

este es el Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Fecha hoy = new Fecha(14,12,2019);

    System.out.println("Hoy es: "+hoy.toString());

    hoy.setDiaSiguiente();

    Persona persona1 = new Persona("Maria","Ortiz",hoy.toString(),"23456122Q","Calle de las Flores","miemail@gmail.com");

    System.out.println("====================\n"+persona1.setPersona());

    Cuenta nueva=new Cuenta(23456785,12,500,persona1.setPersona(),345,200,300,150);

    System.out.println(nueva.setPersona());
}

}
```

Que puedo estar haciendo mal ?

Comment: De primeras he visto varios fallos en el código. Y en la forma que defines los métodos, hay que echarle un buen tiempo para poner bien el ejercicio. Al menos para el error de `cuenta` puede ser que el fallo lo este provocando el `persona1.setPersona()` en la instancia del `Main`

Comment: Llevo varios días sin exagerar dándole vueltas al ejercicio pero no logro saber que estoy haciendo mal, ni como puedo hacer que de un objeto pase a otro un atributo por ejemplo fecha a fechanacimiento y salga correcto cuando lo llame en el main

Comment: Voy a copiarme el código y le hecho un ojo a ver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te coloco las tres clases corregidas:

**PERSONA**

```
public class Persona {

     //variables
     private String nombre;
     private String apellidos;
     private Fecha fechaNacimiento;
     private String dni;
     private String direccion;
     private String email;

     //constructor
     public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos, Fecha fechaNacimiento, String dni, String direccion,String email) {

         this.nombre = nombre;
         this.apellidos = apellidos;
         this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento; //asignamos fecha de nacimiento al metodo anteriormente creado para dar formato.
         this.dni = dni;
         this.direccion = direccion;
         this.email = email;
    }

    //setter
    public String getFechaNacimiento() {

        return fechaNacimiento.toString();
    }

    public String getPersona() {

    return "Nombre:"+this.nombre+"\nApellidos:"+this.apellidos+"\nFecha de nacimiento:" + this.fechaNacimiento
            +"\nDNI:"+ this.dni+"\nDireccion:"+this.direccion+"\nEmail:"+this.email;
      }

}
```

> Como puedes ver ahora en el constructor cuando pides la fecha de
>   nacimiento, ahora si es de tipo Fecha.

**FECHA**

```
public class Fecha {

    //variables
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int anyo;

    //constructor
    public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anyo) {
      this.dia = dia;
      this.mes = mes;
      this.anyo = anyo;
    }

    //metodo
    public String toString(){

      return this.dia + "-" + this.mes + "-" + this.anyo; //creamos la frase devolviendo un string
    }

    //setters y getters
    public boolean esBisiesto(){ //creamos un metodo para comprobar si es bisiesto

     return  ((anyo % 4 == 0) && (anyo % 100 != 0) || (anyo % 400 == 0));

    }

    public int getTotalMes() { //creamos un metodo para establecer la duracion total del mes

        if (mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12){

            return 31;

        } else if(mes == 2){

            if(esBisiesto()){

                return 29;
            }
            else{

                return 28;
            }
        }

        return 30;
    }

    public boolean getFechaCorrecta() { //comprobar si la fecha es correcta

        if(anyo >= 0){

            return false;
        }

        if (mes < 1 || mes > 12){

            return false;       
        }

        if (dia > 1 && dia < getTotalMes()){

            return true;    
        }   
            return false;
    }

    public void DiaSiguiente() { //metodo para sumar 1 dia a la fecha

        if (dia < getTotalMes()){

            dia++;
            System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);

        } else {

            dia = 1;

            if (mes == 12) {

                anyo++;
                mes = 1;
                System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);

            } else {

                mes++;
                System.out.println("Mañana es: "+dia+"-"+mes+"-"+anyo);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**CUENTA**

```
public class Cuenta {

    //variables
    private int numCuenta;
    private int interes;
    private int saldo;
    private Persona cliente;
    private int total;
    private int ingreso;
    private int reintegro;
    private int transferencia;

    //constructor
    public Cuenta(int numCuenta, int interes, int saldo, Persona cliente, int total, int ingreso, int reintegro,int transferencia) {
        this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
        this.interes = interes;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.total = total;
        this.ingreso = ingreso;
        this.reintegro = reintegro;
        this.transferencia = transferencia;
    }

    //metodos setters y getters

    public int getNumCuenta() {
    return this.numCuenta;
    }

    public void setNumCuenta(int numCuenta) {
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    }

    public int getInteres() {
    return this.interes;
    }

    public void setInteres(int interes) {
    this.interes = interes;
    }

    public int getSaldo() {
    return this.saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public String getCliente() {

    return cliente.getPersona();    
    }

    public void setCliente(Persona cliente) {

    this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
    return this.total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
    }

    public int getIngreso() {
    return this.ingreso;
    }

    public int getReintegro() {
    return this.reintegro;
    }

    public int getTransferencia() {
    return this.transferencia;
    }

    public boolean setIngreso(int ingreso) {

        boolean ingresoOk = true; //inicializamos ingreso en true

        if (interes < 0) { //si interes es menor que 0 ingreso es false

            ingresoOk = false; 

        } else { 

            total = total + interes; //sino sumamos el interes con el total de la cuenta
        }

        return ingresoOk;
    }


    public boolean setReintegro(int reintegro) {

        boolean reintegroOk = true;  //inicializamos reintegro en true

        if (interes < 0) {

            reintegroOk = false; //si reintegro es menor que 0 reintegro es false

        } else if (total >= interes) { //sino si total de la cuenta es mayor o igual al interes

            total -= interes; // total menos interes

        } else {

            reintegroOk = false;
        }

        return reintegroOk;
    }

    public boolean setTransferencia(int transferencia) {

        boolean transferenciaOk = true; //inicializamos la transferencia en true

        if (interes < 0) {

            transferenciaOk= false; // si es interes en menor a 0 es false

        } else if (total >= interes) { //sino si el total es mayor o igual al interes

            setReintegro(interes); //llamamos a los metodos anteriores
            setIngreso(interes);

        } else {

            transferenciaOk = false; 
        }

        return transferenciaOk;
    }

}
```

> Ahora en `Cuenta` también esta recogiendo el cliente como tipo
>   Persona.

He estado probando en el `Main` y puedo acceder a los métodos e imprimir cualquier dato sin ningún problema. Realmente no se muy bien que pide el ejercicio para implementar en el `Main`.

Como opinión: deberías revisar bien la lógica de los métodos y cambiar el nombre de algunos métodos, para darle un poco mas de sentido a su funcionalidad.

También deberías de tabular bien el código para que sea mas legible tanto para ti como los demás.

Te dejo la clase `Main` que he probado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Fecha nacimiento = new Fecha(14,12,2019);
    Persona p1 = new Persona("Maria","Ortiz",nacimiento,"23456122Q","Calle de las Flores","miemail@gmail.com");
    Cuenta c1 = new Cuenta(23456785,12,500,p1,345,200,300,150);

    System.out.println("Hoy: " + nacimiento.toString());
    nacimiento.DiaSiguiente();
    System.out.println(c1.getCliente());

    }  
}
```

Comment: Hola! madre mia te daría un abrazo jajaja muchas gracias por ayudarme! me podia volver loca, no me aclaraba para nada,he estado revisando tu corrección y tus comentarios para entender que era lo que fallaba, cuando declaras una variable y viene de otro objeto en vez de int, string, etc.. colocamos el nombre del objeto si he entendido bien verdad? y en el main lo que yo no sabia era que debi colocar el nombre del objeto para hacer referencia al objeto en si y asi se le pasan los datos cierto ?

Comment: Aun te cuesta un poco entender el paradigma de POO por lo que veo jeje. Pero si, cuando creas un objeto, que seria la instancia de la clase, es como si crearas otro tipo de dato.

Comment: Eso no nos lo explicaron en clase, la verdad es que voy haciendo como puedo, a ver si poco a poco voy comprendiendo todo mejor enserio gracias por tomarte el tiempo en ayudarme :)

Comment: Pues ya sabes, cualquier duda me hablas por dis, o subes pregunta y si puedo te respondo!

Answer (score -1):

Hay dos problemas en la clase Cuenta

1-En el constructor cambia el `this.cliente` por

```
this.cliente = cliente;
```

2-Borra `this.cliente = setPersona();` de la función `setPersona()`

Y respecto a tu error de la fecha en la clase Persona cambia el `this.fechaNacimiento` por

```
this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
```

Comment: Entonces como hago que cliente tenga los atributos del objeto persona? Y la fecha de nacimiento este unida con el objeto fecha?

Comment: Si te refieres a que la clase Cuenta tenga los atributos de clase Persona primero tienes que cambiar el atributo "private String cliente" por "private Cliente cliente" luego tienes que modificar todo para que funcione respecto a eso